Base clock (frequency) setting is required in Ubuntu 20.04
enter image description here
I'm currently using ubuntu 20.04 on an HPE DL380 Gen10 server.
The CPU is using Xeon 4216.
The problem is that the CPU in question has a base clock of 2.1GHz.
When checking with Turbostat or cat /proc/cpuinfo, one core body is connected at approximately 800MHz to 1.2GHz.
Checking the test servers used by CentOS, etc. have Olympic verification at 2.1 GHz.
BIOS settings are similar. Even if you set cpufreq, cpupower, etc. in your OS, you're asking it to keep the default clock engaged like Centos. I would like to inquire as to how to access the fixed Base Clock.
What's even more unusual is that the same Ubuntu 20.04 and CPU are used, but the kubernetes service is operated and the base clock of the server is confirmed to be 2.1 GHz, which is inconvenient, and other servers are confirmed because they have clocks. Similarly, BIOS and OS settings are the same.
Cleaning up the environment explains it.
leaf condition
ubuntu 20.04 & openstack server: 800MHz~1.2GHz
centos 7.9 & openstack server: 2.1GHz
ubuntu 20.04 & Kubernetes server: 2.1GHz

BIOS & OS settings are the same. Only the service and OS are different.

I would like to play around with the reason or inquire as to whether there is a way to access the Base Clock so that the OS, etc. can handle the Base Clock. As detailed, tuned, cpufreq, cpupower, etc. were not possible.
thank you

Please edit your question adding the actual outputs you are referring to from checking with Turbostat or cat /proc/cpuinfo . I suspect you are observing frequency scaling, which is normal.

hello.
Thank you for leaving a comment.
An image was added to the first line of the post. Since I'm a newbie, I can only attach photos as links.
thank you.

The "base Clock" is the "TSC_CLK" which is stable at 2.1 GHz. The CPU clock is scaling down on each CPU because it is idle. This is normal.

hello.
Thank you for leaving a comment.
Is it possible to manually set it to that clock?
According to CPU spec
I want minimum 2.1GHz and maximum 2.9GHz.
I have ubuntu 20.04 and cpufreq, cpupower,tuned etc had no effect.

I do not use cpupower, and only use direct commands. I would do echo 2100000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq and then check it with grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq . But note that the processor itself can still back off the CPU clock if the system is idle enough and that the clock turns off entirely for CPUs in a deep enough idle state.

Thank you for your comment.
However, even if you try this setting, there is no change. Is there any other way?

I found your post while looking for previous posts.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1425452/server-cpu-stuck-at-800-mhz-even-under-high-load-with-ubuntu-20-04-4-and-intel-p?rq= One
Is there a possibility that the minimum frequency can be fixed by modifying the msr module? Or is this information only valid under load?

If you are not seeing the scaling_min_freq as 2100000 with the check command after the set command, as in my comment above, then something else is changing it back. You need to disable whatever service is changing it back. I am a server person, and never run any of those services and so don't even know to look for. And yes, you might need some CPU load to observe useful CPU frequencies.

Thank you for your comments.
Scale_min_freq is 2.1GHz, and if you check with cpufreq, cpupower, etc., the setting is 2.1GHz. In other words, the module seems to claim 2.1GHz.
But as you said, the other thing would be to change it again, so is there a candidate for what that "other thing" is like?
Thank you.

From your turbostat listing one can observe the your base clock is stable at 2.1 GHz. What you are observing is the processor itself scaling backing off the CPU frequency because your system is very idle. This behaviour is normal. The behaviour can be altered by disabling the C1E idle, if your system has it.
Let's show an example using my i5-10600K processor, with a base frequency of 4.1 GHz:
Note 1: This example is using: The intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver; The Powersave CPU frequency scaling governor; HWP enabled (typically this is the default); The TEO idle governor; /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq is set to the base frequency of 4.1 GHz (it would be 2.1 GHz for your processor).
Note 2: the default kernel for my COMETLAKE processor does not use the C1E idle state. I had to compile a custom kernel for this answer.
Example:
root@s19:/home/doug# turbostat --quiet --show CPU,Busy%,Bzy_MHz --interval 60
CPU     Busy%   Bzy_MHz
-       0.06    4637
0       0.01    3950
6       0.01    3548
1       0.22    4654
7       0.11    4624
2       0.29    4775
8       0.00    2568
3       0.01    3577
9       0.00    3832
4       0.00    3385
10      0.00    3036
5       0.12    4574
11      0.00    3676

Observe the system is very idle, and several listed CPU frequencies are below the specified minimum of 4.1 GHz.
Now identify and disable the idle state that is using C1E:
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpuidle/state*/name
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpuidle/state0/name:POLL
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpuidle/state1/name:C1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpuidle/state2/name:C1E
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpuidle/state3/name:C3
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpuidle/state4/name:C6
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpuidle/state5/name:C7s
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpuidle/state6/name:C8
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpuidle/state7/name:C9
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpuidle/state8/name:C10

Oh, it is idle state 2:
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpuidle/state2/disable

And now:
root@s19:/home/doug# turbostat --quiet --show CPU,Busy%,Bzy_MHz --interval 60
CPU     Busy%   Bzy_MHz
-       0.04    4662
0       0.01    4165
6       0.23    4657
1       0.00    4100
7       0.00    4101
2       0.15    4780
8       0.00    4100
3       0.00    4101
9       0.06    4671
4       0.00    4102
10      0.00    4308
5       0.01    4101
11      0.00    4159

Observe the system is till very idle, but the listed CPU frequencies are never below the set minimum of 4.1 GHz.

Thank you for your detailed response.
I'll try to test it.
I will update you after testing it.
Thank you so much!

hello. The information you provided has been set, but has not been changed. The changes are as follows.
C1E Disable
cpupower -> modify scaling_minfreq
There was no difference in the results, so we proceeded with adding the settings below.
/etc/default/grub
intel_pstate = disable
thank you.

You should also try using the intel_pstate driver, but with HWP (HardWare Pstate) control disabled. intel_pstate=no_hwp in the  /etc/default/grub file.
